# VueJS Evaluating on Escaped Characters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've run into a bit of an issue when running VueJS.  It feels like it is a bug, but I'm not 100% sure.  When I have HTML with escaped double curly braces, it still gets evaluated by the engine.

https://jsfiddle.net/judda/ge042znc/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="body">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="bar in foo">{{ bar }}</li>
    </ul>
    &#123;&#123; foo &#125;&#125;
  </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  data: function() {
    return {
        foo: ['bar', 'foobar',] 
    };
  },
    el: '#body',
});
```

The output that I would expect to see is:

```
<body>

  <div id="body">
      <ul><li>bar</li><li>foobar</li></ul>

      {{ foo }}
  </div>
</body>
```

However, what I get is:

```
<body>      
  <div id="body"><ul><li>bar</li><li>foobar</li></ul>
    ["bar","foobar"]
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there any way that I am able to stop this from happening?

Comment: Maybe `<span v-html="'{{ foo }}'"></span>`? https://jsfiddle.net/ge042znc/2/

Comment: The problem with that is if the input has single quotes in it then it'll be un-escaped and blow other things up.

Comment: Not if it's an expression instead of a string literal (`v-html="prop"`). If you are embedding a literal, then you already have control over it. https://jsfiddle.net/ge042znc/3/

Comment: The HTML is being injected (and not stored in JavaScript/VueJS) - with this it fails because of the quotes.

https://jsfiddle.net/ge042znc/4/

Comment: Could the injected html have backticks? You could use template literal syntax, depending on your target environment. https://jsfiddle.net/ge042znc/5/

Comment: Do all browsers support the backtick syntax yet?  If that is the case, then I could probably do that.

Comment: All but IE :( http://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need use the `v-pre` or `v-html` directive:

```
<span v-pre>{{ foo }}</span>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre

```
<span v-html="'{{ foo }}'"></span>
```

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very
> dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use
> HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided
> content.
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: There is an opportunity for the text that I am adding in to contain both single/double quotes - so I don't believe that this will work.  I tried to replace a single quote with `&#39;` and it still gets evaluated with the issue.

Comment: Really, it seems to be a kind of bug or it's intentional. It is worth posting this directly on the issues of Vue JS

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was looking for something like that, but my Google-foo failed me!